# How to use NavLink-activeStyle on React with a dropdown link

Tags: reactjs, routes, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I am having a problem adjusting bootstrap 4 navbar to react. I have the following code:

```
<li className="nav-item">
     <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/home" activeStyle={{ color: 'black' }}>Home</NavLink>
</li>
<li className="nav-item dropdown">
    <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Subjects
    </a>
    <div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to="/subjectA">Subject A</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to="/subjectB">Subject B</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to="/subjectC">Subject C</NavLink>  
    </div>
</li>
<li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about" activeStyle={{ color: 'black' }}>About</NavLink>
</li>
```

I want "Subjects" to change to black when a subject is chosen. I know I can use a click event but I want it also to **stay black when I refresh the page**. This is what happens on the other elements because of the NavLink's activeStyle, but seems like I can't use it the same way on the "Subjects" element.

Any idea how I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
const activeStyle = { color: "#000000" };
<li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/home" activeStyle={activeStyle} exact>Home</NavLink>
</li>
<li className="nav-item dropdown">
    <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Subjects
    </a>
    <div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to="/subjectA" activeStyle={activeStyle}>Subject A</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to="/subjectB" activeStyle={activeStyle}>Subject B</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to="/subjectC" activeStyle={activeStyle}>Subject C</NavLink>  
    </div>
</li>
<li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about" activeStyle={activeStyle}>About</NavLink>
</li>
```

- The activeStyle variable just helps you not to repeat that same string all over
- The first "exact" string on "/home" will make sure only the exact path will get the color you want since all your paths are very distinct from each other you can skip that, this was only in case you were using e.g. "/"  which is part of the other routes too.
- The only actual important missing part on your code is the activeStyle={activeStyle} part on your /subjectX routes.

Comment: please don't write link-only answers, try to elaborate.